# Mockito unit test - test calculator method with argument

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to test my method with argument with Mockito.
In my opinion I didn't understand the rules of the mockito operation.
I got this from Android Studio:

```
Comparison Failure: 
Expected :view.showResultCalculation(4);
Actual   :view.showResultCalculation(0);
```

My test:

```
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Mock
    Calculator calculator;
    @Mock
    IMainActivity.View view;

    private MainActivityPresenter presenter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        presenter = new MainActivityPresenter(calculator);
        presenter.setView(view);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_addNumber_when_buttonCLicked(){
        presenter.doCalculate(2,2);
        verify(view).showResultCalculation(4);
    }

}
```

My calculator have only one method:

```
     public class Calculator {

    public int addition(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

My presenter have this method:

```
@Override
public void doCalculate(int a, int b) {
    getView().showResultCalculation(calculator.addition(a,b));
}
```

and my View - main activity - have this method:

```
@Override
public void showResultCalculation(int result) {
    this.result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
```

In real using, this calculator works, and we got 2+2=4, but test give result 0.

What I should fix here ?

Comment: Looks like you're mocking the calculator. `@Mock Calculator`. But I don't see that you've mocked the `addition` method. Is it possible that your mock calculator is returning 0 for any input?

Comment: yes, this calculator in test always return 0, but only in test

Comment: why are you event bothering to mock the `Calculator` class for this? Surely you would presently do `when(calculator.addition(eq(2), eq(2))).thenReturn(4);` or something similar?

Comment: that's a bad design , MVP clean?

Comment: So you've answered your own question then. If the calculator always returns 0 in tests (because it's mocked), That is why you're getting `Actual   :view.showResultCalculation(0);`. The view is called with the result from the mocked calculator. There are a number of simple solutions. The simplest fix, as Mark said, is to _not_ mock the calculator in this test. (Use a real instance instead.)